# Check my answer - Finding the jacobi matrix of a function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, normed-spaces

We are given $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ such that:

$0 \neq x \in \mathbb R^n$, $f(x)=\frac{x}{|x|}$, where $|x| = \sqrt {x_1^2 +x_2^2+...+x_n^2}$

Find the jacobi matrix (the differential matrix) of $f$.

My solution:

I realized that if $x= \begin{pmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\ \vdots \\x_n \end{pmatrix}$ and $f_1(x_1)= \frac{x_1}{|x|}$ and $f_2(x_2)=\frac{x_2}{|x|}$ and so on then:

where $i\neq j$ $$\frac{df_k(x_i)}{dx_j}=-\frac{x_ix_j}{|x|^3}$$

and  $$\frac{df_k(x_i)}{dx_i}=\frac{|x|^2-x_i^2}{|x|^3}$$

**explanation:**

$$f_k(x_j)=\frac{x_j}{\sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}}$$, then if we derive by $x_i$ then we get $$\frac{-0.5*2x_i*|x|^{-1}*x_j}{|x|^2} = -\frac{x_ix_j}{|x|^3}$$

and if we derive by $x_j$ then the result will be $\frac{|x|^2-x_j^2}{|x|^3}$

So to sum up, in my opinion the jacobi matrix looks like this:

in the diagonal, in entry $(i,i)$ we have: $$\frac{|x|^2-x_i^2}{|x|^3}$$

and not on the diagonal. in entry $(i,j)$ we have $$-\frac{x_ix_j}{|x|^3}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jacobian matrix is correct, but you did something wrong.

You're taking $f=(f_1, \ldots ,f_n)$, where $f_k\colon \mathbb R^{\color{red}n}\to \mathbb R, x\mapsto \dfrac{x_k}{|x|}$, for each $k\in \{1, \ldots ,n\}$.

So the entry $(i,j)$ at each point $x\in \mathbb R^{\color{red} n}$ is given by $\dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(x)$.

Your computations are correct, but if I understood what you did correctly, you need to evaluate all the functions at $x$, not at $x$'s components.

Comment: No. this is not what I did. I took $f=(f_1,...,f_n)$ such that $f(x)=(f_1(x_1),f_2(x_2),...,f_n(x_n))$ meaning for every $k$ it holds that $f_k: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ they are all scalar functions.

Comment: @OriaGruber Please define $f_1$ for me. Domain and 'rule'.

Comment: you're right. it is indeed from R^n.